# jQuery Mobile Collapsible set - stop audio player when element is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, audio

Hello guys I hope you can help me with this problem ...

I dynamicly insert the Collapsible set from an XML file. When one element of the Collapsible set is opened you can start a track. However, when another element is opened and the old one is closed the track still plays. Is there any way to pause or just stop the player from playing the track?

I use this script to insert XML data in the Collapsible set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "arheologija.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {

                var container = document.getElementById("catalogue");
                container.setAttribute('data-role', 'collapsible-set');

                $(xml).find('artifakt').each(function () {
                    var release = document.createElement("div");
                    release.setAttribute('data-role', 'collapsible');
                    var cat = $(this).find('slika').text();
                    var title = $(this).find('ime').text();
                    var artist = $(this).find('posnetek').text();
                    var tracks = "";
                    var player = "<audio preload=&quotnone&quot><source src=&quotmiles.mp3&quot></audio>"

                    $(this).find('ime').each(function () {
                        tracks = tracks + $(this).find('ime').text() + "<br>";
                    });
                    release.innerHTML = "<h3>" + title + "<br>" + cat + "</h3><p>" + cat + "</p><audio controls><source src='" + artist + "'></audio>";
                    container.appendChild(release);

                });
                $('#ranking1').replaceWith('<div id="ranking1" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"></div>');
                var catDiv = $('#catalogue');
                catDiv.find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({
                    theme: 'c',
                    refresh: false
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: which jqm version are u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply listen to `expand` *(jQM 1.3)* / `collapsibleexpand` *(jQM 1.4)* events.

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", function (e) {
  $("audio").each(function () {
    $(this)[0].pause();
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ymHbB/)**

Comment: thanks for help... but it doesnt work .... 
I use JQM 1.4 ...
when i click another element the audio still plays ...

Comment: @LitBe use `collapsiblecollapse` event.

Comment: $(document).on("collapsiblecollapse", function () {
  $("audio")[0].pause();
});

Is this ok ?

Comment: Sorry, `collapsibleexpand` instead. @LitBe

Comment: yes the demo works ... but seems that collapsable set works in a different way... couse it doesn't  work in my code ... :S